# Could not find matching constructor for com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(java.io.StringWriter)

Tags: arrays, json, xml, groovy, soapui

I am trying to compare database values to API values on soapui, same testcase but different steps.

First step stores a list from database, second step compares values to API

Database response:

```
<Results>
   <ResultSet fetchSize="128">
      <Row rowNumber="1">
         <PortalId>87776</PortalId>
         <ItemKey>Asset</ItemKey>
         <ItemValue>Customer Equipment</ItemValue>
         <ItemPluralValue>Customer Equipment</ItemPluralValue>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="2">
         <PortalId>87776</PortalId>
         <ItemKey>AssignedBy</ItemKey>
         <ItemValue>Assigned By</ItemValue>
         <ItemPluralValue>Assigned By</ItemPluralValue>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="3">
         <PortalId>87776</PortalId>
         <ItemKey>AssignedTo</ItemKey>
         <ItemValue>Assign/Appointment</ItemValue>
         <ItemPluralValue>Assign/Appointment</ItemPluralValue>
      </Row>
   </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

Script to save database response:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase

//Create the xml holder object for the jdbc response
def holder = new XmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContent)


def nodes = holder.getDomNodes( "//Row" )

// create list of XML strings
def list = []

for( node in nodes )
{
   java.io.StringWriter writer = new java.io.StringWriter()
   com.eviware.soapui.support.xml.XmlUtils.serialize( node, writer )
   list.add( writer )
}

// store in context for later access
//this is really hacky
WsdlTestCase.metaClass.myList = list
```

This works as intended

Then script to compare values in other step

JSON response:

```
{
   "totalRows": 32,
   "results":    [
            {
         "key": "Asset",
         "value": "Customer Equipment",
         "pluralValue": "Customer Equipment",
         "portalId": 87776
      },
            {
         "key": "AssignedBy",
         "value": "Assigned By",
         "pluralValue": "Assigned By",
         "portalId": 87776
      },
            {
         "key": "AssignedTo",
         "value": "Assign/Appointment",
         "pluralValue": "Assign/Appointment",
         "portalId": 87776
      }]
}
```

Second Script;

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper

//get dictList from previous step
def dictList = context.testCase.myList

//get json from response
def jsonResponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(messageExchange.responseContent)

//put json response to an array
def list = jsonResponse.results 

//enumarate the array
list.eachWithIndex { item, index ->

        def dict = dictList[index]
        def obj = item

    //put the dict xml to a var
    def holder = new XmlHolder(dict)

    //compare the database values to API Values
    assert obj.key == holder.getNodeValue('//*:ItemKey') 
    assert obj.value == holder.getNodeValue('//*:ItemValue') 
    assert obj.pluralValue == holder.getNodeValue('//*:ItemPluralValue') 
    assert obj.portalId.toString() == holder.getNodeValue('//*:PortalId')
}
```

Now both scripts have 
`import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder`

but second script fails with below error :

> Could not find matching constructor for com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(java.io.StringWriter)

Why ?

Comment: What is the response in the second script? Is it json? By the way, please add the xml text instead of image. Also add full stacktrace? Are you getting the above error in first script?

Comment: @Rao yes it is a JSON response, I have added the response. First script works fine, Second Script throws the error.  How do I see full stack?

Comment: Stacktrace available in the error log tab below. Can you please add the xml text instead of image?

Comment: Okay, that is the only error I get. I don't see anything in Error log, but in Script Assertion-Failed it prints `Could not find matching constructor for com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(java.io.StringWriter)`

Comment: By the way, you do not have to write in two scripts, instead both can be done in single script. Let me give a try for the solution. Thank you for the question edit.

Comment: I know but we are trying to separate the database connection part and api comparison part , when we have about 50 steps and either one of them fails we could find and report the results easily. Appreciated for help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149145/discussion-between-rao-and-u-gen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Script assertion for the Json test step.

Please follow the in-line comments for more details.

```
//Script Assertion for the Json Step
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'

//Replace the JdbcStepName in the below
def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.testCase.testSteps['JdbcStepName'].responseContent)

//Json response - which is current step
def parsedJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)

//Sort the list of maps using below criteria
def sortByKey = {a, b -> a.key <=> b.key }

//Create the list from jdbc xml response and sort it
def buildXmlDataList = {
    parsedXml.'**'.findAll{ it.name() == 'Row'}.collect{ [key: it.ItemKey.text(), value: it.ItemValue.text(), pluralValue: it.ItemPluralValue.text(), portalId: it.PortalId.text() as Integer]}.sort(sortByKey)
} 

//Create the list from json response and sort it
def buildJsonDataList = {
    parsedJson.results.sort(sortByKey)
}

//Pring it; if using in soapui then use log.info instead of println
println buildXmlDataList()
println buildJsonDataList()

//Assert both the data
assert buildXmlDataList() == buildJsonDataList()
```

Note that the above script does read the Jdbc Xml Response directly unlike you storing it at `WsdlTestCase` using metaClass which is not really required.

Comment: `def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.testCase.testSteps['NameOfTheJDBCRequest'].responseContent)` worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

in the first script you are creating list of `new java.io.StringWriter()`
and store it into `myList`

in the second script you try to create [com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/xmlholder.html) for each item of `myList` and there is no such constructor in this class that accepts StringWriter as parameter.

Just change in your first script this line:

```java
list.add( writer )
```

to this one

```java
list.add( writer.toString() )
```